# How to set the selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make when button in table click I can edit datatable, I following this code

```
 $('#datatable').on('click', '.btn[name="edit"]', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    var ststable = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
    var awal = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
    var akhir = row.cells[5].innerHTML;

    let sts = $("#statusmtr option").map(function() {
      var dt = $(this).val();
      var opsi = "<option value='" + dt + "'>" + dt + "</option>";
      return opsi
    }).get();

    row.cells[3].innerHTML = "<select name='ststable'>" + sts + "</select>";
    row.cells[4].innerHTML = "<input class='form-control' name='awal' value='" + awal + "'>";
    row.cells[5].innerHTML = "<input class='form-control' name='akhir' value='" + akhir + "'>";
    row.cells[8].innerHTML = "<button type='button' name='save' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fas fa-save'></i></button>"
  });
```

this code work, the problem is select dropdown when I click edit the dropdown always showing first data, how to set the selected dropdown showing data like same datatable, I get value databale `var ststable = row.cells[3].innerHTML;`

Comment: you can add selected attribute in <option> based on condition.

Comment: I try this
"<option value ='"+ dt +"' "+(ststable == dt) ? "selected" : "" +"'> but not working :(
help me..

Comment: please share your html also. It will make my task easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectedIndex to achieve that and it is supported by almost all the browsers. Follow the link below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value for the select and trigger the change event.

```
$('#datatable').on('click', '.btn[name="edit"]', function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
  var ststable = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
  var awal = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
  var akhir = row.cells[5].innerHTML;

  let sts = $("#statusmtr option").map(function() {
    var dt = $(this).val();
    var opsi = "<option value='" + dt + "'>" + dt + "</option>";
    return opsi
  }).get();

  row.cells[3].innerHTML = "<select name='ststable'>" + sts + "</select>";
  row.cells[4].innerHTML = "<input class='form-control' name='awal' value='" + awal + "'>";
  row.cells[5].innerHTML = "<input class='form-control' name='akhir' value='" + akhir + "'>";
  row.cells[8].innerHTML = "<button type='button' name='save' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fas fa-save'></i></button>";
  
  // trigger the selected value;
  $('select[name="ststable"]').val(ststable).trigger('change');
});
```